# How to Update php in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-7

I would like to update the versions of php available in Netbeans 7.1 (I know it is only for hints), 
I have php 5.4 working in my pc, but in netbeans I have available only  php5.3 and 5.2, I would like to have 5.4 too

https://prnt.sc/fqxyoo

*I can not update netbeans because from 7.2 to 8.x it crashes inmediatelly after starting, but that is another history, so I would like only how to add php5.4 in netbeans 7.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version with the help of `phpinfo()`. But netbeans does not bundle the php. Check in [php download url](http://php.net/) and download what you want.

Comment: it is running 5.4, but even if I change my php version, it does not affect the one that is in netbeans, I would like to updated the php version that uses netbeans for the hints of the code

Comment: did you try to download and install it?

Comment: yes, no matter what version I install, the version of the php of netbeans does not change

Comment: Right click on project ->properties -> source -> <Change the version> if this not works, please update your netbeans

Comment: I will try that, Thanks